# How to print the size in bytes of new create file

Tags: bash

In the Bash script,
write a simple program that first creates a new file called myfile.txt, then append the string "Hello world" to it. Then print out the size in bytes of myfile.txt.

Comment: "In the Bash script..." I do not understand how java and node.js come into this. Or did you just add those tags in order to first attract and then annoy experts on those topics, along with unnecessary noisy formatting?

Comment: What have you searched for and what have you tried?  How did it fail?

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a blind homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. To improve have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and at [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash the solution would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create new file called myfile.txt
touch myfile.txt

# Append the string "Hello world" to the file
echo "Hello world" >> myfile.txt

# Print the size in bytes of myfile.txt
filesize=$(wc -c < myfile.txt)
echo "File size: $filesize bytes"
```

I don't know what this has to do with node.js or java - please provide further information

Comment: Please confirm that you are aware of the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and that you made a conscious decision to spoon feed here. You can, it is your decision; but it should be a conscious decision.

Comment: Apart from that, if you find that a question raises the need for clarification questions, especially some which already are asked in clarification questions in comments on the question, then it might indeed not be the time to create an answer....

Comment: I'd use `stat -c "%s" file` to get the size instead of `wc`.

Comment: The `stat` command line utility is not in POSIX.  Some platforms don't have it, and there are several variants on the platforms that do have it.   `wc -c` is POSIX, and many implementations (including the GNU one) use the `stat` system call to get the file size in bytes when run with an ordinary file as input, so there's no performance advantage to using the `stat` command line tool in this case.  See the [answer by Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321502/264812) to [How can I get the size of a file in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16640/264812).